# Could not find method compile() for arguments Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Looked around for this solution for much too long now, and I'm not sure if I missed it or just misstyped something, but my Gradle script will not compile. I am migrating to Gradle, and am very new with it. I am very used to using Maven for dependency management, but Gradle seems best me for now. From running this snippet of code:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.bukkit', name: 'bukkit', version: '1.7.9-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
  compile('io.ibj:MattLib:1.1-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group: 'de.bananaco'
    exclude 'net.milkbowl:vault:1.2.27'
  }
  compile group: 'net.citizensnpcs', name: 'citizens', version: '2.0.12'
  compile group: 'com.sk89q', name: 'worldedit', version: '5.6.1'
  compile group: 'com.sk89q', name: 'worldguard', version: '5.9'
  compile group: 'net.milkbowl', name: 'vault', version: '1.2.12'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
}
```

**NOTE:** I do have the java, maven, nexus, shadow, and rebel plugins applied.

When I run my Gradle task, I encounter this error:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [[io.ibj:MattLib:1.1-SNAPSHOT], build_1b5iofu9r9krp7o8mme0dqo9l$_run_closure2_closure8@66fb45e5] on root project 'project'
```

If I remove the `MattLib` dependency from my project and reinsert it as

```
compile 'io.ibj:MattLib:1.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

The script completes, but I have dependency issues. I read up here:

```
dependencies {
  compile("org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0") {
    exclude module: 'shared'
  }
}
```

(From Chapter 50 From [the Gradle Manual](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html))

that what I have SHOULD work, but I am confused why it doesn't.

`gradle --version` output:

```
Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue. Someone on the discussion forum recommended putting exclude inside a compile block, but whenever I try to do so, I get this exact error.

Comment: Hi,

Sometimes we need to check gradle-wrapper.properties - distributionUrl whixh I used 7 and reverted back to 6.1 and working fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be `exclude module: 'net.milkbowl:vault:1.2.27'`(add `module:`) as explained in documentation for `DependencyHandler` [linked from here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#dependencies(groovy.lang.Closure)) because `ModuleDependency.exclude(java.util.Map)` method is used.

Comment: Looking back all this time, this is the most likely problem I was having. I have since obviously far moved on, but after getting notifications that this question was still open I think its only proper to indicate this as the 'correct' answer, as it appears to be the closest.

Answer (score 804):

Note that the `compile`, `runtime`, `testCompile`, and `testRuntime` configurations introduced by the Java plugin have been deprecated since [Gradle 4.10](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) ([Aug 27, 2018](https://gradle.org/releases/)), and were finally removed in [Gradle 7.0](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) ([Apr 9, 2021](https://gradle.org/releases/)).

The aforementioned configurations should be replaced by `implementation`, `runtimeOnly`, `testImplementation`, and `testRuntimeOnly`, respectively.

Comment: i wish there's some RSS feeds that we can subscribe to stay updated with such updates

Comment: @JustKhaithang absolutely not. This is pull not a push problem. Better docs or a better language would be the choices. I'd largely prefer 1.

Comment: @Meshugah , what do you mean by pull or push ?

Comment: ggs on just changing the commands without a fallback or documentation entry

Comment: If you're using Ionic with Capacitor 4 comment `jcenter` from your Gradle to proceed

Comment: Interesting that the **latest & greatest** Android Studio (2021.3.1.17) itself is the one that inserted the outdated `compile` into the auto generated `build.gradle` during an impressively successful import of an old Eclipse/ADT project.

Comment: This saved me time on working an old build.gradle file. I have worked with gradle before, but hadn't used earlier versions and had this problem.

Comment: i know nobody but the most jnr person works on open source, but this is sososo dumb

Comment: Geat answer FTW

Answer (score 185):

Make sure that you are editing the correct `build.gradle` file. I received this error when editing `android/build.gradle` rather than `android/app/build.gradle`.

Comment: I had it in the wrong place too. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: wat do u mean by wrong place?which gradle file am supposed to edit?

Comment: @guru_001 You are supposed to edit android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Why the F.. they named it the same??

Comment: thank you, felt like a real noob trying to solve this

Answer (score 126):

`compile` is a `configuration` that is usually introduced by a plugin (most likely the java plugin) Have a look at the gradle userguide for details about configurations. For now adding the java plugin on top of your build script should do the trick:

```
apply plugin:'java'
```

Comment: the order in which this definition goes seems to have an impact on the build; in my case, i faced the issue with the jar() tag and Rene's note helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: while working with kotlin, had to apply kotlin plugin `apply plugin: "kotlin"`

Comment: My syntax sugar was          plugins {
    id 'java'
}

Answer (score 10):

In my case the problem was mismatch in the gradle version. I have installed gradle **on mac** using

```
brew install gradle
```

and got the latest gradle which was 7.0

However when I cloned by project repo and executed the gradle taks it failed with below error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'digital-engineering-course'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web, build_bzpgd6h32w4m8umtmgs76ewog$_run_closure3$_closure8@b55ca3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

`build.gradle` file looked pretty normal to me as it has regular dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    } 
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
```

It took me a while to understand the problem is mismatch of version. Gradle is not able to find the method `compile()` because I was using gradle 7.0 in my bash.

And the project was supposed to be ran with gradle 4.8 (Actually gradle wrapper was to be used, but that was breaking for another interesting issue `Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`
(If interested [please follow this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67839118/1503163))

The reason for failure is compile is that the **compile**, **runtime**, **testCompile**, and **testRuntime** configurations introduced by the Java plugin have been deprecated since Gradle 4.10, and were finally removed in Gradle 7.0.

So, to solve the problem I had to install the lower version of gradle. If you want to manage multiple version of gradle use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) (earlier known as gvm)

Installation on macOs / linux is as simple as executing below

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Once done use

```
sdk list gradle
```

It will list out all the available versions of the gradle. As per your need install and use. for e.g

`sdk install gradle 4.8` (this will choose the 4.8 by default in current shell)
`sdk use gradle 4.8` (if already installed, this is suffice to switch between gradle version)

And now the `build.gradle` was able to compile and execute the task.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, all the `compile` statements has somehow arranged in a single line. separating them in individual lines has fixed the issue.

Comment: yes if we modify gradle properties from module settings dialog it happen

Comment: True. Damn gradle.build file generator removes newline separators in  dependencies block after some manipulations.

Comment: oh really? come on google what a bug, it removed all my new lines when i woke up and hit the run button! this is really a shit man..

Answer (score 6):

Add the dependency to your **project-level** `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Add the plugin to your **app-level** `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**app-level** `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove some files that were created by gradle at some point in my study to make things work. So, cleaning up after messing up and then it ran fine ...

If you experienced this issue in a git project, do `git status` and remove the unrevisioned files. (For me `elasticsearch` had a problem with `plugins/analysis-icu`).

`Gradle Version`        : 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue:

It was because of gradle version, `compile` command is expired and was replaced by `api/implementation`, and In gradle 7.0+, it was removed.

I still want to use `compile`, so I downgrade gradle version to gradle 4.10.

In file `gradle-wrapper.properties`, use  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip`

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record: I accidentally enabled **Offline work** under *Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Gradle -> uncheck Offline Work*, but the error message was misleading