# Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I cleaned the whole project by deleting local directories like `~/.gradle`, `~/.m2` `~./android` and `~/workspace/project/.gradle` and chosing `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...` in Android Studio.
Now execution of the command `./gradlew` leads to the following output:

```
usr$ ./gradlew tasks
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Needless to say, I deleted too much, the question is how can it be repaired again? Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You should be able to run `gradle wrapper` again to regenerate the missing code... this is assuming you have no source control setup.

Comment: Do you have gradle installed on your machine? You can try invoking regular gradle instead of gradlew, should probably restore gradle wrapper as well.

Comment: The funny thing is that I encountered this error when I changed my project folder name in Hindi.

Comment: try use local gradle home instead of project it self

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Your gradle wrapper is missing, broken or corrupted.

--
**What is gradle wrapper:**

`gradlew` is the gradle wrapper executable - batch script on windows and shell script elsewhere. The wrapper script when invoked, downloads the defined gradle version and executes it. By distributing the wrapper with your project, anyone can work with it without needing to install Gradle beforehand. Even better, users of the build are guaranteed to use the version of Gradle that the build was designed to work with.

--
**Restoring gradle wrapper:**

It used to be that you needed to add a `wrapper` task to your `build.gradle` to restore gradle wrapper and all its dependencies. For instance in `build.gradle`:

```groovy
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '4.1'
    }
```

Or in `build.gradle.kts`:

```groovy
    tasks.register<Wrapper>("wrapper") {
        gradleVersion = "4.1"
    }
```

Newer versions of gradle do not require this. It is now a built-in task. Just run:

```
gradle wrapper
```

You can also supply additional flags to specify versions etc

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.2 --distribution-type all
```

When you run this task, a gradle wrapper script, and the required jar files are added to your source folders. Properties are stored in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

(You may need to install gradle locally to run this. `brew install gradle` on mac for instance. See more detailed instructions [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html#installation))

--
**Why was it missing in the first place?**

OP seems to have deleted something that gradle wrapper depends on.

But a common reason is that a .gitignore entry prevents wrapper jars from being checked into git. Note that the .gitignore in effect may be in the source folder, or a global one in your user home folder or git global configuration. It is common to have a `*.jar` entry in .gitignore.

You can add an exception for gradlew's jar files in .gitignore

```
*.jar
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```

or force add the wrapper jar into git

```
git add -f gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```

--
Ref: [Gradle Wrapper](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

Comment: Another possible cause for this error is to have the  gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar file not executable, e.g. if you copied files from Windows...

Comment: I had this case and eventually executing gradlew.bat with no arguments fixed it.  Don't know why, but worth a try.

Comment: Saved my day! I ignore gradle-wrapper.jar with "*.jar", so I build failed with same problem on pipeline.

Comment: I always appreciate an answer that includes a proper explanation of what's going on, not just a few lines to copy-paste to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You nailed it RaGe. That is exactly what is happening in my case

Comment: I get the same error while running `./gradlew wrapper`.

Comment: `gradle wrapper` gradle: command not found

Answer (score 317):

In addition to @RaGe's answer may be the situation I faced where i had a global git ignore that was ignoring `.jar` files and so the gradle wrapper jar was never being committed.  Thus I was getting that error on the Jenkins server after an attempted `/var/lib/jenkins/my_project/gradlew build`.  I had to explicitly force an add of the jar and then commit:

```
git add -f gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```

Comment: a life saver: thank you! I had already upvoted so apparently I've been burned by this multiple times

Comment: Although this answer has not been picked, this works for me. I did not aware that even I can run `./gradlew`, it does not mean that the necessary /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar exists (which as the answer suggested, it has been ignored by git). Adding it back solved the problem.

Comment: Quite on spot for me!! After checking this answer I noticed that the wrapper jar is missing in my git repo. Executed the above line and pushed.. It worked. :)

Answer (score 77):

What worked for me is to first run:

```
 gradle wrapper
```

After successful build I was able to run

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

> Note: To be able run `gradle wrapper` first run `brew install gradle`. If installation successful run `gradle wrapper` from project root.

Source and thanks: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html and https://stackoverflow.com/users/745574/rage

Comment: In case this command does not work, on AS there is Gradle panel on right side. Click `Gradle->ProjectName->ProjectName->Tasks->build setup->wrapper`

Comment: Working for me.

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue on springBoot project on IntelliJ IDE, this suggestion resolved the issue. Thank you @niklasingvar

Comment: It worked for me, I could execute the task wrapper from Eclipse IDE. From console didn't work. Thank you!!

Answer (score 47):

In my case it was a global `.gitignore`, [as explained in @HankCa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622432/5893392).

Instead of forcefully adding the jar, which you'll need to remember to do in each Gradle project, I added an override to re-include the wrapper jar in my global `.gitignore`:

```
*.jar
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```

This is useful to me as I have many projects that use Gradle; Git will now remind me to include the wrapper jar.

This override will work so long as no directories above `gradle-wrapper.jar` (such as `gradle` and `wrapper`) are ignored -- [git will not descend in to ignored directories for performance reasons](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: Yes this is the problem same in my case

Answer (score 30):

In my case, I left out <kbd>wrapper</kbd> sub folder while copying <kbd>gradle</kbd> folder and got the same error.

**Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain**

make sure you have the correct folder structure if you copy wrapper from other location.

```
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

Comment: Why would you copy wrapper? Simply executing `gradle wrapper` will give you the exact same result ;)

Comment: @Xerus, in some corporate env there are network restrictions that you can not freely download packages. in this case you have to copy/move.

Answer (score 16):

I just copied `gradle-wrapper.jar` from one of my previous projects from path `/android/gradle/wrapper` and pasted into my app on the same path `/android/gradle/wrapper` and it worked perfect.

Chill Pill :)

Comment: This is what fixed it, but I had a small difference, where I was using fastlane on GitHub action, and those files have been added to .gitignore in the same project.. so just remove them from the gitignore file and push them.

Answer (score 12):

I followed the answers from above when i ran into this. And If you are having this issue than make sure to force push both jar and properties files. After these two, i stopped getting this issue.

```
git add -f gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
git add -f gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

Answer (score 11):

You are probably missing `gradle-wrapper.jar` file under directory `gradle/wrapper` in your project.

You need to generate this file via this script in build.gradle file as below,

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
   gradleVersion = '2.0' // version required
}
```

and run task:

```
gradle wrapper
```

With gradle 2.4 (or higher) you can set up a wrapper without adding a dedicated task:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.3
```

OR

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-distribution-url https://myEnterpriseRepository:7070/gradle/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip
```

All the details can be found [this link](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/release-notes.html#generate-wrapper-with-specific-version-from-command-line)

Comment: Lots of errors on windows 10 for "gradle wrapper --gradle-distribution-url https://myEnterpriseRepository:7070/gradle/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip"

Comment: Yes, the problem is missing the content of `gradle/wrapper` dir. This can be remedied by running the `gralde wrapper` as you stated.

Comment: In case this command does not work, on AS there is Gradle panel on right side. Click `Gradle->ProjectName->ProjectName->Tasks->build setup->wrapper`

Answer (score 8):

In my case (using windows 10) gradlew.bat has the following lines of code in:

```
set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%
```

The APP_HOME variable is essentially gradles root folder for the project, so, if this gets messed up in some way you are going to get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

For me, this had been messed up because my project folder structure had an ampersand (&) in it. Eg C:\Test&Dev\MyProject

So, gradel was trying to find the gradle-wrapper.jar file in a root folder of C:\Test (stripping off everything after and including the '&')

I found this by adding the following line below the set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME% line above. Then ran the bat file to see the result.

```
echo "%APP_HOME%"
```

There will be a few other 'special characters' that could break a path/directory.

Comment: What was the fix for this?  I'm trying to avoid moving my project.  Thanks!

Comment: GAAAAA.  This was my issue.  This answer is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 7):

I saw the same error but in my case it was a fresh Git installation without LFS installed. The repo in question was set up with LFS and the gradle-wrapper.jar was in LFS so it only contained a pointer to the LFS server. The solution was simple, just run:

```
git lfs install
```

And a fresh clone did the trick. I suppose `git lfs pull` or just a `git pull` could have helped as well but the person with the problem decided to do a fresh clone instead.

Comment: Exactly what happened over here, too ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The problem statement is simple that its not able to locate the executable main class file.

If you are using gradle wrapper in your project, you should have strucutre as below

```
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
```

When you execute ./gradlew , it looks for the classpath and as per the code in gradlew or gradlew.bat, there is a line to add gradle-wrapper.jar to classpath

**CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar**

Now in my case there was an entry in the .gitignore as *.jar which excluded the gradle-wrapper.jar as well when the first commit was made.

So, to bring back the file, you have to execute below task

```
gradle wrapper
```

If you are not using latest gradle version then you have to have a wrapper task in build.gradle as below. This defines which gradle version will be bundled in wrapper. For latest versions of gradle, wrapper task is implicit.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.8' 
    //change this as per your project. Refer to distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties to confirm the version
}
```

Once you execute the task, the gradle-wrapper-4.8.jar will be downloaded and dropped in the gradle/wrapper folder (as explained in above tree structure). Rename the file to gradle-wrapper.jar

However, as *.jar was excluded in the .gitignore file, I still cannot checkin it to store in github.

So add the below line in the .gitignore file to exclude gradle-wrapper.jar from ignored jars list due to *.jar.

```
!gradle-wrapper.jar
```

Git has actually shared sample .gitignore files for all programming languages.

Please refer for gradle andjava

- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Gradle.gitignore
- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore

Comment: The path diagram was useful. It made me realize that I was missing the gradle-wrapper.jar file, which had been ignored in git -- just like your explanation.

Comment: @TylerForsythe I am happy if this helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you can also copy the gradlew.bat into you root folder and copy the gradlew-wrapper into gradlew folder.

that's work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this in the OS X and solved as below:

```
$ gradle wrapper
```

Now, you can run the `build` command,

```
 $ ./gradlew build
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MacOS and the `./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` file already exists but it still throws the same error, it might be due to MacOS java permissions on the Documents folder.

Go to `System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy Tab -> Files and Folders -> Java`, and check the "Documents folder" checkbox (or any other that might appear where you are holding your apps).

I fought with this thing for hours so I hope it's useful for someone.

Answer (score 4):

The global gitignore was ignoring all `.jar` and `.properties` file.
Hence my `gradle/wrapper` was not added to the commit.

adding them back helped resolve the issue

Comment: This was exactly my problem as well; running `git add --force ./wrapper` and committing the results did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

[image: gradlew main]

copy **gradlew-wrapper.jar** from other project in **[your project]/gradle/wrapper**

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem with next fix (maybe it will help someone):

Just check if the parent folders of your project folder have names with spaces or other forbidden characters. If yes - remove it.

"C:\Users\someuser\Test Projects\testProj" - on this case "Test Projects" should be "TestProjects".

Answer (score 1):

@HankCa solved the problem in my case as well. I decided to change my dangerous `**/*.jar` ignores to self-explanatory ones like `src/**/lib/*.jar` to avoid such problems in the future. Ignores starting with **/* are a bit too hazardous, at least to me. And it's always a good idea to get the idea behind a .gitignore row just by looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case gradle-wrapper.jar got corrupted after replacing a bunch of files. Reverting to original one resolved the problem.

Comment: Hey@Neek Welcome to Stack overflow please give answer on the new question this question have already more than 4 answer accepted so please concentrate on that part.

Comment: Sure! all the above accepted answers did not help me so I put what helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case , I had removed gradlew and gradle folders from project.
Reran clean build tasks through "Run Gradle Task" from Gradle Projects window in intellij

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Gradle 5.x I use:

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error because my app was in a folder that have an Arabic name and I solve it with just changing the Arabic folder name to an English one and it works fine.

So make sure that all the path of your app is written in English.

Answer (score 1):

1. from one of your any running project copy the folder of Gradle.
2. replace it in your current project

then rebuild
i hope you will be find working well.

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle version 5+, this command solved my issue :

> gradle wrapper

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled gradle and reinstalled it and then created a new wrapper.

```sh
$ sudo apt remove gradle
$ sudo apt-get install gradle
$ gradle wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was that the `gradle-wrapper.jar` file kept getting corrupted by git.

**We had to add a `.gitattributes` file with the line:**

```
*.jar binary
```

Then remove the jar from git and add it again. Weirdly enough that was only required for one of our repos but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

It also might happen that you lost execution rights on the gradle folder, so

```sh
sudo chmod -R +x ./gradle
```

will help to fix the problem.