# gradlew assemble failing on Travis-CI

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

I'm trying to get a private build to behave on Travis-Ci Pro but it keeps complaining because `./gradlew assemble` is failing. Here's the full log:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-4002cef1.prod.travis-ci.com:travis-linux-15

travis_fold:start:system_info
[0K[33;1mBuild system information[0m
Build language: java
Build group: stable
Build dist: precise
[34m[1mBuild image provisioning date and time[0m
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
[34m[1mOperating System Details[0m
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
[34m[1mLinux Version[0m
3.13.0-29-generic
[34m[1mCookbooks Version[0m
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
[34m[1mGCC version[0m
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[34m[1mLLVM version[0m
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
[34m[1mPre-installed Ruby versions[0m
ruby-1.9.3-p551
[34m[1mPre-installed Node.js versions[0m
v0.10.36
[34m[1mPre-installed Go versions[0m
1.4.1
[34m[1mRedis version[0m
redis-server 2.8.19
[34m[1mriak version[0m
2.0.2
[34m[1mMongoDB version[0m
MongoDB 2.4.12
[34m[1mCouchDB version[0m
couchdb 1.6.1
[34m[1mNeo4j version[0m
1.9.4
[34m[1mRabbitMQ Version[0m
3.4.3
[34m[1mElasticSearch version[0m
1.4.0
[34m[1mInstalled Sphinx versions[0m
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
[34m[1mDefault Sphinx version[0m
2.2.6
[34m[1mInstalled Firefox version[0m
firefox 31.0esr
[34m[1mPhantomJS version[0m
1.9.8
[34m[1mant -version[0m
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
[34m[1mmvn -version[0m
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
travis_fold:end:system_info
[0K

Installing an SSH key from: default repository key
Key fingerprint: 23:d9:a6:24:7b:c4:67:d8:c6:45:13:5c:0f:56:04:92

travis_fold:start:git.checkout
[0Ktravis_time:start:06c3823f
[0K$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=cli-interface git@github.com:atomicpages/java-grader.git atomicpages/java-grader
Cloning into 'atomicpages/java-grader'...
remote: Counting objects: 62, done.[K
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (1/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   4% (2/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   6% (3/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   8% (4/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  11% (5/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  13% (6/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  15% (7/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  17% (8/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  20% (9/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  22% (10/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  24% (11/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  26% (12/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  28% (13/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  31% (14/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (15/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  35% (16/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  37% (17/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  40% (18/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  42% (19/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  44% (20/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  46% (21/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  48% (22/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  51% (23/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  53% (24/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  55% (25/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  57% (26/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  60% (27/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  62% (28/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  64% (29/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (30/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  68% (31/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  71% (32/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  73% (33/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  75% (34/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  77% (35/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  80% (36/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  82% (37/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  84% (38/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  86% (39/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  88% (40/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  91% (41/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  93% (42/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  95% (43/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  97% (44/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (45/45)   [K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.[K
Receiving objects:   1% (1/62)   
Receiving objects:   3% (2/62)   
Receiving objects:   4% (3/62)   
Receiving objects:   6% (4/62)   
Receiving objects:   8% (5/62)   
Receiving objects:   9% (6/62)   
Receiving objects:  11% (7/62)   
Receiving objects:  12% (8/62)   
Receiving objects:  14% (9/62)   
Receiving objects:  16% (10/62)   
Receiving objects:  17% (11/62)   
Receiving objects:  19% (12/62)   
Receiving objects:  20% (13/62)   
Receiving objects:  22% (14/62)   
Receiving objects:  24% (15/62)   
remote: Total 62 (delta 13), reused 54 (delta 5), pack-reused 0[K
Receiving objects:  25% (16/62)   
Receiving objects:  27% (17/62)   
Receiving objects:  29% (18/62)   
Receiving objects:  30% (19/62)   
Receiving objects:  32% (20/62)   
Receiving objects:  33% (21/62)   
Receiving objects:  35% (22/62)   
Receiving objects:  37% (23/62)   
Receiving objects:  38% (24/62)   
Receiving objects:  40% (25/62)   
Receiving objects:  41% (26/62)   
Receiving objects:  43% (27/62)   
Receiving objects:  45% (28/62)   
Receiving objects:  46% (29/62)   
Receiving objects:  48% (30/62)   
Receiving objects:  50% (31/62)   
Receiving objects:  51% (32/62)   
Receiving objects:  53% (33/62)   
Receiving objects:  54% (34/62)   
Receiving objects:  56% (35/62)   
Receiving objects:  58% (36/62)   
Receiving objects:  59% (37/62)   
Receiving objects:  61% (38/62)   
Receiving objects:  62% (39/62)   
Receiving objects:  64% (40/62)   
Receiving objects:  66% (41/62)   
Receiving objects:  67% (42/62)   
Receiving objects:  69% (43/62)   
Receiving objects:  70% (44/62)   
Receiving objects:  72% (45/62)   
Receiving objects:  74% (46/62)   
Receiving objects:  75% (47/62)   
Receiving objects:  77% (48/62)   
Receiving objects:  79% (49/62)   
Receiving objects:  80% (50/62)   
Receiving objects:  82% (51/62)   
Receiving objects:  83% (52/62)   
Receiving objects:  85% (53/62)   
Receiving objects:  87% (54/62)   
Receiving objects:  88% (55/62)   
Receiving objects:  90% (56/62)   
Receiving objects:  91% (57/62)   
Receiving objects:  93% (58/62)   
Receiving objects:  95% (59/62)   
Receiving objects:  96% (60/62)   
Receiving objects:  98% (61/62)   
Receiving objects: 100% (62/62)   
Receiving objects: 100% (62/62), 13.52 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/13)   
Resolving deltas:  38% (5/13)   
Resolving deltas:  46% (6/13)   
Resolving deltas:  53% (7/13)   
Resolving deltas:  69% (9/13)   
Resolving deltas:  76% (10/13)   
Resolving deltas:  84% (11/13)   
Resolving deltas:  92% (12/13)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
travis_time:end:06c3823f:start=1450114509982135009,finish=1450114510406203180,duration=424068171
[0K$ cd atomicpages/java-grader
$ git checkout -qf d3c067dead18a524bf85efb7eb90cad63d47368c
travis_fold:end:git.checkout
[0K
[33;1mThis job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.[0m
[33;1mIf you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml[0m
[33;1mSee http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.[0m
$ jdk_switcher use oraclejdk8
Switching to Oracle JDK8 (java-8-oracle), JAVA_HOME will be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
$ export TERM=dumb
$ java -Xmx32m -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
$ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
javac 1.8.0_31
travis_fold:start:install
[0Ktravis_time:start:16e15912
[0K$ ./gradlew assemble
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

[31;1mThe command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.[0m

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

[31;1mThe command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.[0m

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

[31;1mThe command "eval ./gradlew assemble" failed 3 times.[0m

travis_time:end:16e15912:start=1450114512754418536,finish=1450114515995381755,duration=3240963219
[0K
[31;1mThe command "./gradlew assemble" failed and exited with 1 during .[0m

Your build has been stopped.
```

I'm not really sure what to do. I followed the gradle setup for a project per the Travis documentation and it should work fine... Here's my travis config file

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7

before_script:
- chmod a+x gradlew

sccript: ./gradlew build
```

If I build locally via IntelliJ IDEA or by the following:

- `gradle build`
- `chmod a+x gradlew && ./gradlew build`

it works flawlessly. Any hints?

Comment: You can open this gradlew in editor and add some echo there. Especially before the last command "exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "$@""

Comment: @AndreyTsarevskiy for whatever reason that escaped my mind lol

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For anyone passing by my issue was in my `.gitignore` file. I inadvertently added this entry:

```
gradle/
```

Which was causing `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` to not be included in my repo. Removing this entry in the `.gitignore` file and committing the changes to the repo fixed the issue.

Comment: Doesn't work here. check https://travis-ci.org/DoubleCiti/laitucao.la/builds/135887492

Comment: thanks, the standard java gitignore that intellij generates for you excludes jars which causes this problem.

Comment: If you ignore *.jar then the problem will still exist. You might want to do !gradle/wrapper/** in that case.

Answer (score 16):

In fact, not only `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` has to be there, but also it should have `-x` permission. So if you already committed it, but it doesnot have `-x`, you should do the following:

1. `chmod +x gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`
2. `git add -f gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`

Reference: [Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain/31622432#31622432)

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to add `.jar` file into your repository, you can install `wrapper` before your build is started on travi-ci:

```
install: gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.2

language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

More about wrapper in [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) and install commands in [travis-ci doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/).

Comment: I like this alternative

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the `gradle-wrapper.jar` in the repository, but it still gave me the:
`Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

It turned out that because of the fact I enforced `LF` line endings in my `.gitattributes` the `gradle-wrapper.jar` file got corrupted during commit.

**To fix it do the following:**

1. In `.gitattributes` add the following line `*.jar binary`
2. Remove gradle wrapper files:
   `rm -rf gradle/ gradlew gradlew.bat`
3. Regenrate the wrapper:
   `gradle wrapper --gradle-version=5.1.1 --distribution-type=all`
4. Commit and push :)

Answer (score 0):

For those it didn't work by above answers, you could try

jdk: openjdk8 instead of oraceljdk8 in .travis file

You can check the difference between oracle JDK and Open Jdk though. It should not matter as both are licenced one from oracle and one from open GNU PL but if you want specific difference you could visit 
-https://www.baeldung.com/oracle-jdk-vs-openjdk