# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My build.gradle for an Android app has become quite lengthy. Chanced upon this plugin called [gradle-lint-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Using-Lint) and configured it properly. In its documentation it says

> Run `./gradlew fixGradleLint` to automatically fix your build scripts

but upon running that I get `Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`.

Does this have anything to do with the Android Studio using its own Gradle plugin? I do not have Gradle installed systemwide.

**Edit**: I do not wish to install Gradle systemwide - is there any way to do this within Android Studio only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain)

Comment: @petey unlike [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain) I do not have gradle installed - only Android Studio.

Comment: try running `./gradlew fixGradleLint` on osx/nix or `gradlew.bat fixGradleLint` on win

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sounds like the wrapper is not setup correctly. Likely missing the wrapper jar.

```
$ ls gradle/wrapper
gradle-wrapper.jar        gradle-wrapper.properties
```

When you look in `gradle/wrapper` do you see `gradle-wrapper.jar`?

if you install gradle you can generate the jar with this command:
`$ gradle wrapper`

Comment: Nope - only `gradle-wrapper.properties` is there. Is there any way to fix/run the Gradle task without installing Gradle?

Comment: no at this point you must install gradle to fix.  Once you run the command above be sure to commit the jar to git, svn or whatever VCS you are using.  After you have the jar you can uninstall gradle and only use the wrapper again but you have to install gradle to fix no matter what.

Comment: thank you for your comment! this is testament to how bloated the architecture of Android Studio is.

Comment: I already have the wrapper committed but every time react-native-git-upgrade messes the wrapper up so I have to check the file out after the upgrade and it works.

Comment: in my case my `.gitignore` file was configured not to commit `*.jar` so I was able to provide an exception via `!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`

Answer (score 4):

I was having this error and I solved it correcting the path which had special caracters.

Ex: .../T&G/appmobile
to ../TG/appmobile

Comment: A student in a course I was TA in was having a similar problem with a path containing a colon in it. Something along the lines of "/Users/name/22:23/project". It was difficult to figure out what was going wrong but your answer helped us find it.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens if you have "&" or "/" kind of special characters in your folder or in the parent folder. Rename those folders and the error is simply gone.