# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I have react native version 0.42.0. My project was working fine with this.

Recently I upgraded to react-native version 0.43.1. and now when I do

```
react-native run-android
```

I am stuck with the error.

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I have followed the instruction for upgrading from
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

I googled the issue. Gone through the following links none of it worked for me.

1. [Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain)
2. [Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508014/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain)
3. [How/when to generate Gradle wrapper files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files)

any kind of help/guidance will be helpfull for me.

Answer (score 12):

Please check your **gradle-wrapper.jar** from `gradle/wrapper` folder.

I got the same error as you and I changed the jar with complete one.

I also changed one line in the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file with `*distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`,
gradle will download itself.

Comment: gradle wrapper.jar file is missing for me, what I did copied  gradle wrapper.jar file from another project.

Answer (score 8):

```
react-native upgrade
```

Running this command might fix your issue. In my case, it did. But make sure to have a backup of Android and iOS folder in case you modified it.

Comment: Running `react-native upgrade` worked for me in that I just had to rebuild the gradle-wrapper.jar file. This can be done by keeping all the existing files (n) when upgrading react-native when prompted to use or replace existing version.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue doing these two simple steps:

1) Delete Android and iOS folders

2) Execute the next line

```
react-native eject
```

3) Run!

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: eject is no longer available.

Comment: in my case i use npx react-native eject

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your gradle-wrapper.jar file size from ~\android\gradle\wrapper , available jar file size is 49 KB
2. Update your gradle-wrapper.properties file distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
3. Add 
   task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
   gradleVersion = '2.10'
   }
   on build.gradle
4. Again, run `react-native run-android`. If you get this error:

   ```
    * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details ,
   ```

   please add `build.gradle` with:

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

       aaptOptions {
           cruncherEnabled = false
           useNewCruncher = false
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have gradle setup in your environment.
You can follow below link to configure gradle and then you can run gradle wrapper again.

Follow the instructions mentioned in below link.
https://gradle.org/install/#manually