# React Native: Failed to install the app. Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I recently started my React Native journey and hit a snag before I could even start to code. I followed the guide by Facebook on how to set up your [environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) for a React Native project, though I installed java SDK, python and node manually instead of through chocolatey. Installing the react native application on my system went smoothly but when I try to run on my Android Emulator by using the command `react-native run-android`, I run into the following Error message.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

*Note: I have not made any changed in any file nor deleted anything*

---

**Steps to reproduce**

- Run the command `react-native init AwesomeProject`
- `cd AwesomeProject`
- Ensure Emulator is running then start Metro Bundler with `react-native start`
- Run command `react-native run-android` in a separate terminal to receive error

---

**Steps taken to resolve**

I have tried following multiple issues and queries of others with similar problems to no avail

- I tried re-installing everything from scratch to no avail, and creating a new project but the same message appears after hours of re-installation
- One person suggested running `gradle wrapper` inside the project folder, but that too made no difference
- Another suggested that a file name `gradle-wapper.jar` would be missing, but its there in the project folder
- I tried loading the Android folder of the react native project in my Android Studio, the gradle starts building but there is still no success when the gradle is built

---

**Packages Installed**

- Node V12.18.2
- Java SDK V8
- Python 2.7
- Android Studio SDK [Android 10.0 (Q)]
- Android SDK Build-Tools (Installed)
- Android Emulator (Installed)
- Android SDK Platform-Tools (Installed)
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) (Installed)

Please let me know if any further information is required to understand my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made changes in the environment variable after installation?

Comment: Umm no, was i supposed to? There was nothing mentioned in the react native docs.

Comment: Yes check in Android development environment in the 3rd step on https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: Oh those, sorry i misunderstood your question. Yes I have configured those. ANDROID_HOME variable has been created and platform-tool, android-sdk and emulator have all been added to path.

Comment: ok may be issue with gradle, check in the android studio if any error while gradle sync

Comment: try to clean gradle in android folder by running command 'gradlew clean' and open android studio and check if any error while gradle sync

Comment: I tried running in android studio, gradle sync finshed successfully without any errors. When i try to clean gradle using `gradlew clean` in the android folder it gives me this error message `Error: could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

Comment: check this if any of these solution works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521533/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain

Comment: Thanks John, i will look into it and let you know if things start to work!

Comment: Welcome :) feel free to ask