# I tried to run gradlew genSources and it is not working

Tags: java, gradle

Everytime I try to run `./gradlew genSources` I get this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

How to I fix this problem?

I tried to rebuild the program and change the JDK's version and it still didn't work, I also checked and the .jar file exists in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508014/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain)