# How to run-android uisng react-native flag in my project. When I run 'npx react-native run-android', it filed at "Installing the app..."

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Here is my terminal run at AndroidStudio and then it failed. As my thought, problem is gradle version, so I tried up and down version (6.8 to 7.1) but it can't solve.

```
C:\WP-Workplaces\TinyR&D\react-native-apps\blue-book-native>npx react-native run-android --verbose

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.

Jetifier found 1222 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...

info Starting JS server...'

info Launching emulator...

info Successfully launched emulator. 

info Installing the app...

debug Running command "cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081"

'D\react-native-apps\blue-book-native\android\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081`

'D\react-native-apps\blue-book-native\android\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

at makeError (C:\WP-Workplaces\TinyR&D\react-native-apps\blue-book-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)

at C:\WP-Workplaces\TinyR&D\react-native-apps\blue-book-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)

at async runOnAllDevices (C:\WP-Workplaces\TinyR&D\react-native-apps\blue-book-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)

at async Command.handleAction (C:\WP-Workplaces\TinyR&D\react-native-apps\blue-book-native\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain) answer your question?

Comment: Do you installed Android environment in your OS?