# flutter Gradle task Assemble Debug failed

Tags: flutter

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
any help ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain)

Comment: no cuz my problem is not java related

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case someone has the same problem
the problem was with the directory of the project
It was in my main folder which has non English characters