# How can I fix my Flutter code which is producing errors?

Tags: flutter

i need fixed this code please i have more problem thank you
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapper

help me please i need fixed ]
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapper

Comment: does it solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805622/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-gradlewrappermain