# Gradle: how to include an existing, complete project as a subproject?

Tags: android, gradle, multi-project

I git clone a complete gradle project "CompleteGradleProjA" from github and include it into my local project as a submodule. By "complete gradle project" I mean that I can go into directory "CompleteGradleProjA" and issue command

```
cd CompleteGradleProjA && gradle build
```

to build it.

My directory structure looks like this,

```
MyProj
  |---CompleteGradleProjA
  |   |---build.gradle
  |
  |---build.gradle
```

My question is: How can I call "CompleteGradleProjA/build.gradle" without changing anything of it from my root "build.gradle"?

The following root "build.gradle" config does not help.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
  compile project(':CompleteGradleProjA')
}
```

I got error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileJava'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileJava'.
```

"CompleteGradleProjA" is an android porject and "CompleteGradleProjA/build.gradle" looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the "apply plugin"  value of CompleteGradleProjA in the gradle file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CompleteGradleProjA/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
// if your project isn't library then use this:
// apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0' // if needed
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':CompleteGradleProjA'
```

Use `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` or `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` instead of `apply plugin: 'java'`

Answer (score 2):

To include a custom project as part of your gradle build, first ensure  the submodule is already included within the project folder and accessible via your **settings.gradle**. i.e.

```
include ':app', ':your_project_name'
```

You then register the project as a dependency of another by using in your project's **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':your_project_name')
}
```

In newer versions compile has been deprecated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910991/2119941) on what to use.