# Could not find method compile() for a multi module project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project('client')
    compile project('-cache
')
```

Now when I comment out `compile project('product-cache-client')` it moves to the next one and compains about that.

I tried to add it to `gradle.settings` in that module like so:

```
include('client')
include('cache')
```

But I still get the same error. I even tried adding this to the `gradle.settings`

```
project('lib/cache').projectDir = "$rootDir/lib/cache" as File
```

And still get the same result.

> Gradle 4.4

main gradle.build file:

```
subprojects {

    dependencies {
        compile project('client')
        compile project('cache')

    }

    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

configure(subprojects){
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}

repositories {

}

buildscript {

    ext {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full set of build files, chasing errors from snippets is an impossible game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the java plugin on top of your parent build, for me this works:

apply plugin:'java'

It is recommended here - the second answer [Could not find method compile() for arguments Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle)
And also switch the 'dependencies' with 'repositories' - at least in the sample of build.gradle you wrote here they are switched.

Comment: But this applies the plugin to subprojects. What if you add it in the top of the parent builg.gradle (your main gradle build).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a support forum, it's a site for questions and answers about programming. Members are not expected to provide personal support by for example screen sharing. Try to resolve your issue by providing more detail and discussion in the comments and by edits to the question.

Answer (score 0):

when you define dependency as `compile` then it can not be accessible at the runtime. If you run the project through IDE then it works but when you run with `gradle bootRun` or `mvn spring-boot:run` command then above error will throw. So have to just replace `compile` with `implementation`.

```
dependencies {
        implementation project('client')
        implementation project('cache')

    }
```