# Could not find method compile() google gms

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to import google play services vision but give me this error:

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Build gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
 }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
     plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
 belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find method compile() for arguments Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not place your application dependencies in top level `build.gradle`, instead use module level `app/build.gradle` to define your app dependencies.

Remove this line from this top level `build.gradle` and move it to app level `build.gradle`.

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
```

Hopefully, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: This save my life