# Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl

Tags: spark-java

I am trying to learn spark java web framework. I am using Intellij and created a new project just added a HelloWorld class, but got this error,

```
Build file '/Users/mingwang/SourceCodes/spark-example/build.gradle' line: 17

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'spark-example'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

My build.gradle is like

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.0.0'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

mainClassName = "HelloWorld"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find method compile() for arguments Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle)

Answer (score 27):

The `compile` statement is deprecated and has been removed in Gradle 7.0. You should use `implementation` or `api` instead. The differences are explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493379).

In your build.gradle, replace

```
compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3"
```

with

```
implementation "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.3"
```