# Unable to create .jar file. Error while working with gradle, particularly ./gradlew build. getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, android, spring, maven, gradle

I was trying to build a jar file. Basically trying to dockerize my project. But I was unable to create a jar file. I was getting error.
While I was running `./gradlew build` I was getting the error:

```
l (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x7fd2416f
```

So, I ran `gradle --stacktrace`, then the following reason of error showed up:

```
e=log4j-api, version=2.14.1}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

## build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.projects'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'
def versionLog4j = '2.14.1'
def versionLombok = '1.18.20'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: versionLog4j
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: versionLog4j
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: versionLombok
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: versionLombok
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

## Java version

```
java 16.0.1 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

## gradle -v

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-07-02 12:16:43 UTC
Revision:     774525a055494e0ece39f522ac7ad17498ce032c

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          16.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 16.0.1+9-24)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Additionally, I have a warning which I can not fix: `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.`

Answer (score 1):

Can You Run the Gradle build with a command line argument --warning-mode=all to see what exactly the deprecated features were used in your build ?

Comment: ```FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.```

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Assignment-14a'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=org.apache.logging.log4j, name=log4j-api, version=2.14.1}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.
DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Based on my understanding Compile() method is removed from Gradle 7.0, Read the Details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle   You need to use the implementation method instead of compile()

Comment: I ran ```docker build -f /Assignment-14a/Dockerfile  -t dockerstoreimage .``` and this is the thing showing up: ```Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them```

Comment: is the Dependency Issue fixed? I have no idea about Dockers. Let me try something

Comment: well, I just used implement instead of compile and it worked. But now I am facing another issue.

Comment: okay, Post the new issue

Comment: will try to sort out

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: versionLog4j
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: versionLog4j
}
```

use:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.14.1'
}
```