# How to include org.jetbrains.annotations to the IDEA Gradle project?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, plugins, annotations

I want to create a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. I install the Intellij IDEA 2021.3 and the Oracle OpenJDK 17.0.1 (also I have tried with OpenJDK 15).

I try to create an empty plugin project following [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/gradle-build-system.html) instruction. I select the Gradle, then check the IntelliJ Platform Plugin, and chois the OpenJDK 17 in the Project SDK list. Then I press next->finish.

The new empty project is opening and after a few seconds I look at the message "*my_plugin:test: Could not find org.jetbrains:annotations:22.0.0.*"

I read the JetBrains [recommendations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html) to add annotations to a project. The recommendations say that *"To add the library with annotations to a Gradle project, add the **compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'** dependency to the build.gradle file"*.

But the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle) on StackOverflow (with links to gradle.org) says that "*the **compile**, runtime, testCompile, and testRuntime configurations introduced by the Java plugin **have been deprecated** since Gradle 4.10 (Aug 27, 2018), and were finally removed in Gradle 7.0 (Apr 9, 2021)*"

Is this the reason for my problem? If yes, what shall I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
In build.gradle I got:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}
```

and

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

For the JDK: I had problems using higher versions, so I'm using version 11.